# Boostrap portfolio items not centered

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, image, gallery, center

Hej!

I am working on a boostrap image gallery, that should be able to shuffle the image items: http://demo.acasaprogramming.ro/shuffle-portfolio/#.

Right now I am just trying to make the gallery work, without the shuffle functionality, but I have run into a problem that spent a lot of time trying to solve.

The items in my gallery is kinda pushed to the side, and I've tried a lot of things including: text-align: center. Setting the padding to be the same on all sides, margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;.... I don't know what I am doing wrong..

I've attached a [picture or my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HRcm.jpg) and as visible by the picture, the images on the left side goes all the way to the border - I want all the items in the middle of the container :/

I added a little section of my html document - hope that is enough (it is the same code for all pictures)

```css
    body 
    {
     background-color: #f1f5f8;
     border-top: 10px solid #2980b9;
    }
 
    .portfolio
    {
     margin: 48px 0;
    }
 
    .portfolio-sorting
    {
     text-transform: uppercase; 
     font-size: 16px;
     margin-bottom: 48px;


    }

 
    .portfolio-sorting li a 
    {
     color: #000000;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 6px;
    }

    .portfolio-sorting li a:hover,
    .portfolio-sorting li a.active
    {
     color: #2980b9;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #2980b9;
    }
```

```html
<section class="portfolio">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
    
          <ul class="portfolio-sorting list-inline text-center">
           <li><a href="#" data-group="all" class="active">All</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" data-group="people">People</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" data-group="simpsons">Simpsons</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" data-group="futurama">Futurama</a></li>
          </ul> <!--end portfolio sorting -->
    
    
    
          <ul class="portfolio-items list-unstyled" id="grid">
    
            <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" data-groups='["people"]'>
              <figure class="portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/700/400/people/1" alt="Item 1" 
                  class="img-responsive">
                </a>
              </figure>
            </li>
    
            <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" data-groups='["people"]'>
                <figure class="portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/700/400/people/7" alt="" 
                        class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </li>
    </ul> <!--end portfolio grid -->
    
    
          </div> <!--end row -->
        </div> <!-- end container-->
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap elements (col-xs-4 for example) have **float** property which is by default set to left.

You have to set **float: none** and **display: inline-block** to those elements.

Also text-align center for parent:

```
.portfolio-items {
    text-align: center;
}

.portfolio-items > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/24/

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zLgO.jpg)

Sorry. Here is the picture of the screen

Answer (score 0):

your issue is with the center column and the 3d translation.

```
<ul class="portfolio-items center-block list-unstyled shuffle" id="grid" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 707.109px; transition: height 250ms ease-out;">

            <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 center-block col-xs-6 shuffle-item filtered" data-groups="[&quot;people&quot;]" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; transition: transform 250ms ease-out, opacity 250ms ease-out; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1);">
              <figure class="portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/700/400/people/1" alt="Item 1" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
              </figure>
            </li>

            <li class="col-md-4 center-block col-sm-4 col-xs-6 shuffle-item filtered" data-groups="[&quot;people&quot;]" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(390px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); transition: transform 250ms ease-out, opacity 250ms ease-out;">
                <figure class="portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/700/400/people/7" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </li>

           <li class="col-md-4 center-block col-sm-4 col-xs-6 shuffle-item filtered" data-groups="[&quot;futurama&quot;]" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(780px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); transition: transform 250ms ease-out, opacity 250ms ease-out;">
              <figure class="portfolio-item">
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/700/400/1" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                  </a>
              </figure>
            </li>

            <li class="col-md-4 center-block col-sm-4 col-xs-6 shuffle-item filtered" data-groups="[&quot;futurama&quot;]" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(390px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); transition: transform 250ms ease-out, opacity 250ms ease-out;">
              <figure class="portfolio-item">
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/700/400/2" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                  </a>
              </figure>
            </li>

            <li class="col-md-4 center-block col-sm-4 col-xs-6 shuffle-item filtered" data-groups="[&quot;simpsons&quot;, &quot;people&quot;]" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0px, 236px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); transition: transform 250ms ease-out, opacity 250ms ease-out;">
              <figure class="portfolio-item">
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/700/400/1" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                  </a>
              </figure>
            </li>

            <li class="col-md-4 center-block col-sm-4 col-xs-6 shuffle-item filtered" data-groups="[&quot;simpsons&quot;]" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(780px, 236px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); transition: transform 250ms ease-out, opacity 250ms ease-out;">
              <figure class="portfolio-item">
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/700/400/3" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                  </a>
              </figure>
            </li>

            <li class="col-md-4  center-blockcol-sm-4 col-xs-6 shuffle-item filtered" data-groups="[&quot;people&quot;]" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(390px, 266px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); transition: transform 250ms ease-out, opacity 250ms ease-out;">
                <figure class="portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/700/400/people/9" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </li>

             <li class="col-md-4 center-block col-sm-4 col-xs-6 shuffle-item filtered" data-groups="[&quot;simpsons&quot;]" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(390px, 236px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); transition: transform 250ms ease-out, opacity 250ms ease-out;">
              <figure class="portfolio-item">
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/simpsons/700/400/4" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                  </a>
              </figure>
            </li>

            <li class="col-md-4 center-block col-sm-4 col-xs-6 shuffle-item filtered" data-groups="[&quot;futurama&quot;]" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0px, 471px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); transition: transform 250ms ease-out, opacity 250ms ease-out;">
              <figure class="portfolio-item">
                  <a href="#">
                      <img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/700/400/5" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                  </a>
              </figure>
            </li>


            <!-- sizer -->
            <li class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 shuffle_sizer shuffle-item filtered" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(780px, 471px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1); transition: transform 250ms ease-out, opacity 250ms ease-out;"></li>


          </ul>
```

you had an extra 30 pixel top and 60 pixel top on two of your columns. This is just the starting on the site link you provided.